# No alarm clock sign in Android 10 when scheduling alarm with AlarmManager#setAlarmClock

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-10.0

My app is an alarm clock app, and I am setting an alarm in the following way:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Activity_AlarmsList.this, alarmID, intent, 0);

ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(alarmDateTime.withSecond(0), ZoneId.systemDefault());

alarmManager.setAlarmClock(new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(zonedDateTime.toEpochSecond() * 1000, pendingIntent), pendingIntent);
```

where `alarmDateTime` is a `LocalDateTime` object containing the alarm date and time.
On Android M and N (real devices), an alarm clock sign appears on the status bar as soon as an alarm is set. But on my Samsung Galaxy M31s (Android Q), no alarm sign appears! But the alarm clock sign appears when I run the app on an Android Q emulator.

In the Samsung Galaxy M31s, if I execute `adb shell dumpsys alarm`, I get the following output:

```
Next wake from idle: Alarm{c9c59a type 0 when 1603225320000 in.basulabs.shakealarmclock}
tag=*walarm*:in.basulabs.shakealarmclock.DELIVER_ALARM
type=0 expectedWhenElapsed=+48s986ms expectedMaxWhenElapsed=+48s986ms whenElapsed=+48s986ms maxWhenElapsed=+48s986ms when=2020-10-21 01:52:00.000
window=0 repeatInterval=0 count=0 flags=0x3
Alarm clock:
  triggerTime=2020-10-21 01:52:00.000
  showIntent=PendingIntent{f26a278: PendingIntentRecord{9c3ed51 in.basulabs.shakealarmclock broadcastIntent}}
operation=PendingIntent{860e9b6: PendingIntentRecord{9c3ed51 in.basulabs.shakealarmclock broadcastIntent}}
```

which is what I want. So the alarm is set, and indeed the alarm rings too, but no alarm clock sign appears.

What is the problem?

Comment: There's no requirement that the System UI on a particular device displays an alarm symbol. That would be entirely up to that manufacturer to decide.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Ok, but the inbuilt alarm clock that comes in the Galaxy M31s shows the alarm symbol when an alarm is set.

Comment: @WrichikBasu: Samsung is welcome to build their firmware such that their own alarm clock has abilities and behaviors that third-party alarm clocks do not.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hmm, you are right. I will customise my app accordingly and show an ongoing notification when an alarm is set. One thing that I believe I can conclude is that there is nothing wrong in the way I am setting the alarm.